# Range based on a certain number of columns/rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm not entirely sure how to word this correctly, but here goes!

I have a formula, let's say: `=IF(SUM(A1:A10)=50,"Yes","No")`

Is there a way that I can identify the range based on the number of rows I want to include based on the value of another cell?

Let's say that cell `B1` value is "10", is there a way to re-write my formula to look something like this:

`=IF(SUM(A1:X)=50,"Yes","No")` where "X" is some sort of formula that calculates "A1 + 10 Rows" (10 would be the variable number based on value of B1, so "A1 + B1 rows")

I need to use the same technique to also adjust the number of columns for another formula as well.

Basically, I'm using a VLookUp with multiple arrays, and the arrays have to be the same size. The amount of columns or rows is dynamic.

So I need to be able to take write a formula, `=COUNTIF($F$1:$F$10<>"")-1` maybe that formula calculates "4".

So I need to adjust my VLookUp to `A1 + 4 rows` as the searchable range, and for another formula, it would be A1 + 4 columns (so A1:E1).

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your value in **B1**, then in another cell:

```
=IF(SUM(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,B1))=50,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

This example uses the value in **B1** to define the number of rows to be `SUM()`'ed. It avoids having to use `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed!! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

in Google Sheets:

```
=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&B1))=50, "Yes", "No")
```